# Read relatively large file in python takes a lot of time

Tags: python-2.7, large-files

i have a file of **265 MB** and **7504527** lines of **text**.
this loop is taking a lot of time running :

```
B = namedtuple("B", ["id", "ch"])

def get_tuple_from_b_string(b_str):
    return B(int(b_str.split("_")[0]),int(b_str.split("_")[1]))

with open("/tmp/file.out") as test_out:
     for line in test_out:
         if line == '' or not line.startswith("["):
              continue
         bracket_index = line.find(']')
         b_str = line[1:bracket_index]
         content = line[bracket_index+1:]
         b_tuple = get_tuple_from_b_string(b_str)
         if not b_tuple in b_tupled_list:
             continue
         if not b_tuple in b_outputs:
             b_outputs[b_tuple] = ''
             b_outputs[b_tuple] += content+'\n'
```

i'm running now and still after 19:38 minutes haven't finished yet.
i tried to check strace of the process and it repeating of the lines :

> mmap2(NULL, 3145728, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS,
>   -1, 0xff9093fc) = 0xfffffffff4997000
>   munmap(0xf678b000, 3145728)

but different addresses (which i assume it's not stuck , and still reading).
**My questions are** :

- why is it taking long time (under the assumption that its not stuck) ?
- if it is stuck , how can i find out where ?

example of file content :

```
[1_03]{
[1_03]    "0": {
[1_03]        "interfaces": {
[1_03]            "address": [],
[1_03]            "distribution": [],
[1_03]            "interface": [],
[1_03]            "netmask": []
[1_03]        },
```

Comment: It's taking a long time because the data is huge. I see you are reading line-by-line. Instead of that, try to read all of it once using a `read()` and then iterate through that line-by-line.

Comment: Can you show us a couple example lines from the file?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi NO! Directly iterating over the file object is better than reading the whole file to ram, splitting it into lines and iterating over that list. By using `read()` you get the entire 265MB of data as single string loaded in your memory. Also the program's waiting for the read to complete before starting to process the data. And what if the file would have a few GB and your RAM is smaller than that? Out of luck! Iterating over the file object reads only one line per loop into the RAM and is much faster and very memory-efficient.

Comment: @Epsilon However, I think as your code is working and you're just looking for optimization, I suggest that this question could be migrated to [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: @JohnZwinck edited the question with some content but it is repetitive it is in fact a big json

Comment: @Epsilon: how many distinct [...] values are there?  That is, how many separate JSON documents are in this file?

Comment: @JohnZwinck the file is a one big json , but there are many of the "0": part in the example ranging from 0 to n , with each one having the interfaces and routes , each list can contain a LOT of routes for example

Comment: @Epsilon: The file is not exactly "one big JSON" because it has all these annoying prefixes on it.  Why are the prefixes there exactly?  What software put them there, and how?  It'd be easier to parse if it were an actual valid JSON file.

Comment: @Johnzwinck sorry my bad , that file contains parts from multiple sources , look at it like that , each source (pc) sends parts of its json , all of them contained in this file , the prefix specifies where each line came from , my job is to separate each json from this file , thats what the loop is doing parsing b ("]") and taking the the line without it .

Answer (score 0):

Some performance optimizations:

```
def get_tuple_from_b_string(b_str):
    # do not split the string twice, map and unpack the split list at once:
    return B(*map(int, b_str.split("_", 2)))

with open("/tmp/file.out") as test_out:
     for line in test_out:
         # omit superfluous test and reverse if logic to remove the 'continue'
         # (probably more a matter of style than performance though...)
         if line.startswith("["):
             # replace finding plus twice slicing with one slice and a split:
             b_str, content = line[1:].split("]", 2)
             b_tuple = get_tuple_from_b_string(b_str)
             # again reversing the if-logic to omit the 'continue'.
             # maybe this could be sped up using a set, depending on what you're doing...
             if b_tuple in b_tupled_list:
                 # 'a not in b' is more clear than 'not a in b'
                 if b_tuple not in b_outputs:
                     # omit the empty assignment, string concatenation is slow!
                     b_outputs[b_tuple] = content+'\n'
```

With these optimizations you should become a bit faster. Especially your string operations are probably the most expensive part, because strings are immutable and each attempt to modify a string will result in creating a copy of that string. This takes time and memory and should be avoided in performance-critical scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of separate JSON documents tagged with a non-JSON prefix on each line.  What I would do first is to use `awk` to split the file back out into multiple valid JSON files, named like 1_03.json.  Then I'd read all those into Python using a fast JSON parser like `ujson` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson).  This would probably be much faster overall.

The `awk` script might be roughly like this (lightly tested):

```
BEGIN {
    FS="]";
}

{
    filename=substr($1, 2)".json"; # e.g. 1_03.json
    $1="";
    print > filename;
}
```

Then it's just a matter of `glob`ing the files in Python and parsing with `ujson`.